# Android Bluetooth output stream to POS printer disconnected

Tags: java, android, sockets, printing, bluetooth

I am using a bluetooth ESC/POS printer to print an invoice from Android device. Invoice has two parts:

1. String with invoice content and
2. QR code.

### Backgound story

Bluetooth socket is created with

```
bluetoothSocket = printer.createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(uuid);
bluetoothSocket.connect();
```

and the output stream is opened with

```
if(bluetoothSocket.isConnected()) outputStream = bluetoothSocket.getOutputStream();
```

I pass invoice to output stream in two steps (at first the invoice content string and then a QR bitmap - both objects are converted to byte array inside the methods that are called) using

```
outputStream.write(data);
```

where `data` is `byte[]`. Before and after printing I call, just in case, the reset method which sends command for initialization.

The printing part is the following

```
Bitmap bitmapQR = QRgenerator.generate();
BluetoothPrinter usersPrinter = new Printer();
usersPrinter.findPrinter();
usersPrinter.connectPrinter(); // init is sent
usersPrinter.sendDataText(invoiceString, EscPosCommands.ALIGN_LEFT); // print invoice string
usersPrinter.sendDataBitImage(bitmapQR); // print QR code
usersPrinter.resetPrinter(); // init is sent once again
//usersPrinter.disconnectPrinter(); // problematic
```

Problematic method that disconnects printer is

```
if(bluetoothSocket.isConnected()) {
   outputStream.close();
   bluetoothSocket.close();
}
```

### Problems

- When the invoice is printed and the disconnect method, which closes the output stream and bluetooth socket, **is called** which the printer stops
  responding. Feed button does not work. Sometimes while printing QR code the printing process stops like the stream closes before the printing is done. I don't understant this behaviour as the disconnect method is called after QR-printing method. I don't see the reason why the printing is being canceled.
- When the invoice is printed and the disconnect method **is not called**, the printer apparently waits for more data for a few seconds (eg. 15 seconds). On the models with status LED the light is on. After that pause the printer is usable again. I believe that printer somehow automatically resets the connection itself and socket remains connected.

### Question

How can I close the connection between Android device and bluetooth
    printer so the printing process will complete successfully and the printer will be ready to print a new invoice without a delay?

---

### Update

I've left Bluetooth socket connected while the app is running. After that I've changed the procedure so that QR code **is not printed last** - at first there's some text printed, then bitmap and then some more text. In that combination there's no lag between printing and printer does not hang.

That makes me wonder if printer stays in raster bit image mode. I've calculated everything again and the command is valid.

Hex command for printing a bitmap is `0x1D 0x76 0x30 m xL xH yL yH d1...dk`. If used for bitmap with dimensions 255x255 px the hex byte array command is

```
0x1D 0x76 0x30 0x00 0x20 0x00 0xFF 0x00 bitmap[8160]
```

where `bitmap[8160]` is series of bitmap bytes with length of 8160 that equals 0x20 * 0xFF.

However, when the printing is done init command is sent to printer so either way the printer **should reset**. Or does it?

Another thing that I've noticed are **line feeds**. If they are sent after every printing part P like P1, feed, P2, feed, P3, feed ... the result would look more like P1, P2, P3, feed, feed, feed. Why is that so?

Comment: The correct way to finish printing is probably described in the technical docs for the printer you're using.  I've worked with several Bluetooth printers, so I can say that we probably couldn't help you even if you told us the exact printer model, because the docs are usually covered by a silly NDA.

Comment: @KevinKrumwiede; well that's the catch. I have to support more than just one printer, for instance Bixolon SPP-R200, OCOM pos thermal printer (some John Doe version I guess) and there will be some others too). Non of them has a really good docs ... everything is based on the general ESC/POS commands. Based on your experience with Bluetooth printers, what is the procedure that worked for one of the devices you worked with?

Comment: I established the Bluetooth connection when the app started and kept it open as long as the app was running.  Some of the printers I was using would not accept connections after they'd been turned on for a few minutes.  That wasn't documented, but it might have been an intentional security measure.  Most receipts required multiple print frames, so I had to wait for the printer to ack and in some cases report busy and ready between frames.